# pcap_next_ex() cannot be used again if it reaches the end of a pcap file

Tags: c++, c, winpcap

I am analysing a pcap file (offline mode). First, I need to count the number of packets already contained in the file. For that I used "pcap_next_ex()" to loop over the file and that always works fine. My second purpose is to pick out each packet time stamp so I called "pcap_next_ex()" again in order to loop over the pcap file and fill timestamp array (I created dynamically based on the number of packets contained in the pcap file).

The problem is that when calling "pcap_next_ex()" (after it has reached EOF)it returns negative value immediately, so I cannot loop over packets to get time stamps and fill my array.

For me it seems like the pointer that read the pcap file is still stuck at EOF and needs to be reinitialized to point to the start of the file. Is my assumption true? If the answer is yes, how to point to the start of pcap file again?

Note: I am using Visual-studio2008, windows7

This is the code:

```
pcap_t * pcap_ds = pcap_open_offline(pcap_file_name.c_str(), errbuf);

    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

const u_char *data;

// Loop through pcap file to know the number of packets to analyse

int packets_number = 0;

while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap_ds, &header, &data) >= 0)
    {
        packets_number++;
}
    // Prepare an array that holds packets time stamps
timeval* ts_array = (timeval *) malloc(sizeof(timeval) * packets_number);

     // Loop through packets and fill in TimeStamps Array 

while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap_ds, &header, &data) >= 0)
    {

    ts_array->tv_sec = header->ts.tv_sec;
    ts_array->tv_usec = header->ts.tv_usec;
            ts_array++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating twice the pcap file just because you want to know how many packets exists in it; that can be avoided easily. You should use a `std::vector` or some other data structure which grows dynamically to store the timestamps:

```
pcap_t * pcap_ds = pcap_open_offline(pcap_file_name.c_str(), errbuf);
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
const u_char *data;

std::vector<timeval> ts_array;
// Loop through packets and fill in TimeStamps Array 
while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap_ds, &header, &data) >= 0) {
    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = header->ts.tv_sec;
    tv.tv_usec = header->ts.tv_usec;
    ts_array.push_back(tv);
}
```

There you go, no need to allocate anything.